# Method.invoke not working with package-private class

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class TableModelBase that extends AbstractTableModel. In there I override the getValueAt method so that it return the getter result of the row class.

**TableModelBase.java**

```
@Log
@AllArgsConstructor
public abstract class TableModelBase<T> extends AbstractTableModel{
    @NonNull private final String[] columns;
    @NonNull protected final transient List<T> rows;

    //...

    /**
     * Default getValue method.<br>
     * The row type fields must be in the same sequence that the columns.<br>
     * Getter methods must follow the getter convention.
     * @param rowIndex The row index.
     * @param columnIndex The column index matches the field index of the row type.
     * @return Object
     */
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        final T row = rows.get(rowIndex);
        if(row.getClass().getDeclaredFields().length != getColumnCount()) {
            for (Field field : row.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                System.out.println(field.getName());
            }
            log.severe("Fields number and table columns number are different in: " + row.getClass().getSimpleName());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        final Field field = row.getClass().getDeclaredFields()[columnIndex];

        String getter;
        if(field.getType().equals(boolean.class)) {
            getter = field.getName();
        }
        else {
            getter = "get" + Character.toUpperCase(field.getName().charAt(0)) + field.getName().substring(1);
        }

        try {
            Method method = row.getClass().getMethod(getter);
            return method.invoke(row);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            log.severe(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a test class TableModelTest in the package tablemodel. In this package there is also the classes Data and DataModel.

**Data.java**

```
@Value
class Data {
    String text = "text";
    boolean isSuccessful = true;
}
```

**DataModel.java**

```
class DataModel extends TableModelBase<Data> {
    DataModel() {
        super(new String[]{"Text", "Is Successful"}, new ArrayList<>());
        rows.add(new Data());
    }
}
```

**TableModelBaseTest**

```
public class TableModelBaseTest {
        @org.junit.Test
        public void getValueAt() {    
            final DataModel dataModel = new DataModel();
            assertEquals("text",dataModel.getValueAt(0, 0));
            assertEquals(true, dataModel.getValueAt(0, 1));
        }
}
```

The test give an  IllegalAccessException:

> Class com.dsidesoftware.tablemodel.TableModelBase can not access a
>   member of class tablemodel.Data with modifiers "public"

The getters are public so why I cannot access them ?
The strange thing is when I make Data public, the exception is gone.

Any idea of what is going on ?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems that Data has 'package only' visibility. That may cause that exception to be thrown. Do you have any reason to not make Data public?

Comment: @Shirkam Well we can imagine a package containing the data class, the model and the table. In such a case only the table should to be public. My question is more about understanding what is happening than solving it in an inelegant manner.

Comment: Wouldn't this be much simpler if you used any map to store your row properties? Also, I suposse that you just didn't write Data getters for brevity.

Comment: @Shirkam The purpose of DefaultTableModel.getValueAt  is to get as less code as possible in the Data like and DataModel like classes. So if I have to map all the fields in all the classes I'd rather just extends the getValueAt method in the TableModels. Concerning the getters, they are generated via Lombok annotations and follow the get+Field() naming convention (or isPropertyTrue() for boolean).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this has to do with the fields in the Data class being package-private. If you want to circumvent this issue, just call `setAccessible(true);` on any `java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject` instances (i.e. Field & Method in your case) immediately after attaining them. This will make the call to `get()` on them ignore security checks.